# What autocmd FileType is in .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I started using twitvim and found [this code code for .vimrc](http://blog.ruedap.com/2011/01/21/vim-twitter-plugin-twitvim).

But I am not sure what the last part of code is trying to do.

```
autocmd FileType twitvim call s:twitvim_my_settings()
function! s:twitvim_my_settings()
  set nowrap
endfunction
```

And this is the original code. I deleted all of `<C-u>`, `<C-w>` and `j`.

```
""" twitvim
let twitvim_count = 40
nnoremap ,tp :<C-u>PosttoTwitter<CR>
nnoremap ,tf :<C-u>FriendsTwitter<CR><C-w>j
nnoremap ,tu :<C-u>UserTwitter<CR><C-w>j
nnoremap ,tr :<C-u>RepliesTwitter<CR><C-w>j
nnoremap ,tn :<C-u>NextTwitter<CR>
autocmd FileType twitvim call s:twitvim_my_settings()
function! s:twitvim_my_settings()
  set nowrap
endfunction
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't use the plugin, but I could try to explain what the meaning of those lines:

```
"this just assigning a variable, may be used by the plugin
let twitvim_count = 40  

" create a normal mode mapping, to execute Posttotwitter command.
" The leading ctrl-u just for removing the range information of the 
"command line. if you removed it, range info will be kept
" all following commands have the same meaning for <c-u>
nnoremap ,tp :<C-u>PosttoTwitter<CR>
" the next 4 commands are same as above, but executing different cmd. the ctrl-w j will move cursor
" to  a "belower" window, the cmd may open a new window/split.
nnoremap ,tf :<C-u>FriendsTwitter<CR><C-w>j
nnoremap ,tu :<C-u>UserTwitter<CR><C-w>j
nnoremap ,tr :<C-u>RepliesTwitter<CR><C-w>j
nnoremap ,tn :<C-u>NextTwitter<CR>

"create autocmd, if the filetype is twitvim, call a function
autocmd FileType twitvim call s:twitvim_my_settings()

"here a function was defined
function! s:twitvim_my_settings()
  "this function just do one thing, set nowrap option. (text is gonna be displayed without wrap.)
  set nowrap
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Q1: what does the range information mean? Q2: what does a "belower" window mean? Q3: filetype means myfile.twitvim? Does it extension? Q4: so I should keep <C-u>, <C-w> etc?

Comment: @shin A1: `:%s/foo/bar/'` is a command, the `%` is range, `C-u` will remove that part, which means the customized command will handle range by itself. A2: belower, I **guess** the command from your plugin will create a window split, and after the executing move cursor to that one. and the split would be below your current `:h Ctrl-w_j` A3: yes  A4: yes, if you don't know what were you doing, and what would be the consequence, I prefer to leave it as it was. And I suggest you reading some help doc for those things not very clear to you. Vim has a great help doc!

Answer (score 23):

While Kent's answer is correct and very detailed, I thought I'd submit a visual version.

```
autocmd FileType twitvim call s:twitvim_my_settings()
|______________________| |__| | |___________________|
           |               |  |          |
           1               2  3          4   

1. Automatically do something when the FileType (the file extension) matches .twitvim
2. call (Vim's way to run a function)
3. Refers to a function local to the current script file
4. The function to be ran
```